# wp8 service reference update

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8, web-reference

I have created a Web service which provides various methods for my Windows phone app. The communication between these two works fine.
My problem is that once I update the Web service (only new methods add. No existing, delete, or modify) must I update the Web reference in my Windows phone app, recompile the project and upload the app in the store.

Is there a way that the existing app will continue to work even if I upload a new version of my Web services? Of course, the new version of the Web service contains the old methods.

BSP:
App Ver1 Calls Method "LoadData"
WS Ver1 Has Method "LoadData" -> OK
WS Ver2 Has Method "LoadData", "Close" -> Should also be OK...

Answer (score 0):

The app should still work, even if you add new functions.  The underlying SOAP call doesn't care if you have new functions.

Comment: Probably I use it the wrong way... I've added the Service Reference called NotificationServie. In my code I write `code`Private WithEvents mobjNotificationService As NotificationService.NotificationServiceSoapClient = New NotificationService.NotificationServiceSoapClient()`code`mobjNotificationService.Endpoint.Address = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(String.Concat(strURL, "/NotificationService.asmx"))`code`mobjNotificationService.GetCurrentStateAsync(clsStatic.Settings.SerialNumber)
`code`
Is there an another way get the Answer? (Late-Binding)